# How to write this query with hibernate using mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to select one row from all 3 tables. The tables have the same structure, 4 columns, "code", "airportname", "latitude", "longitude".

The query I am trying to write is:

> select
>   finnairroute.code,finnairroute.airportname,finnairroute.latitude,finnairroute.longitude,lhroute.airportname,lhroute.latitude,lhroute.longitude,sasroute.code,sasroute.airportname,sasroute.latitude,sasroute.longitude
>   FROM frs.sasroute, frs.finnairroute,frs.lhroute where
>   sasroute.code="BER" or finnairroute.code ="BER" or lhroute.code
>   ="BER";

Tested with Mysql workbench and I got this result:

[image]

How should I write the query in order to get one single row that has all the info for "BER"?

Many thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far? if so what is the occuring hibernate / jpa problem?

Comment: What is not clear to me is whether there is a unique row in either of the three tables for a given code, or if there is one row in each table

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT finnairroute.*,lhroute.*,sasroute.* FROM DUAL
LEFT OUTER JOIN finnairroute ON (finnairroute.code='BER')
LEFT OUTER JOIN lhroute ON (lhroute.code='BER')
LEFT OUTER JOIN sasroute ON (sasroute.code='BER')
```

The thing is that you will always get one row, even if the code is in none of the table. You need to test whether finnairroute.code, lhroute.code and sasroute.code are null or not.

Another way to approach the problem:

```
SELECT 'finnair' as company,code,airportname,latitude,longitude FROM finnairroute WHERE code='BER'
UNION SELECT 'lh' as company,code,airportname,latitude,longitude FROM lhroute WHERE code='BER'
UNION SELECT 'sas' as company,code,airportname,latitude,longitude FROM sasroute WHERE code='BER'
```

This gives you between zero and three rows, depending on what tables contain the code 'BER'. An additional column, 'company' tels you which table contains each row.